# Use Monotone Convergence theorem to prove that the following sequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series

Use Monotone Convergence theorem to prove that the following sequence converges.  $$ $$  $a_{1}=5 ; \ a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3}(5a_{n}-1) \ \ \forall \ n \in \mathbb{N} $ $$ $$ My approach: $ Since \ \ a_{1}=5 , a_{2}=8, a_{3}=13, a_{4}=64/3 , ...... $ . So the sequence is monotonic incraesing and lower bound is **5**. But how to get the upper bound and thereby applying Monotone Convergence theorem to ensure convergence of the sequence ?  **Any help  ?**

Comment: This looks like it's increasing very rapidly. Are you sure you have the right problem?

Comment: Hint: $a_{n} \ge n\,$ so the sequence diverges. Another way to see it is that, if the sequence converged to $A\,$, then $A=(5A-1)/3 \iff A=1/2\,$.

Comment: Yes the problem is  absolutely right. How to show formally that it has no upper bound ?

Comment: If $ A=1/2 $ , then what would I get from here ?

Comment: Once you proved it's increasing, you have that $a_n \ge a_1 = 5\,$, so the limit cannot be $\lt 5\,$.

Answer (score 6):

$\require{cancel}a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{1}{3}(5a_{n}-\bcancel{1})-\frac{1}{3}(5a_{n-1}-\bcancel{1})=\frac{5}{3}(a_{n}-a_{n-1})=\cdots=\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^{n-1}(a_2-a_1) \gt 0\,$, so the sequence is increasing.

Moreover, $\,\lim_{n \to \infty} (a_{n+1}-a_n) = (a_2-a_1) \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{5}{3}\right)^{n-1} = +\infty\,$, so the sequence diverges.